# How do we mention or tag someone in using Slack's Block Kit Builder?

Tags: slack, slack-block-kit

I tried creating slack's block kit builder, the desired design were actually fine. But I don't know where to find a button so we can tag a someone on it.

---

I have here an attempt to tag a person named *john* but unfortunately it only generated a plain text, it did not notify the person nor became the same the design as expected (see image result below)
[view playground](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/T02HTGREMTJ#%7B%22blocks%22:%5B%7B%22type%22:%22section%22,%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22@juan%20%5Cn%5Cnis%20a%20mrkdwn%20section%20block%22%7D%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22image%22,%22title%22:%7B%22type%22:%22plain_text%22,%22text%22:%22I%20Need%20a%20Marg%22,%22emoji%22:true%7D,%22image_url%22:%22https://assets3.thrillist.com/v1/image/1682388/size/tl-horizontal_main.jpg%22,%22alt_text%22:%22marg%22%7D%5D%7D)

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "@juan \n\nis a mrkdwn section block"
            }
        },
        .....
    ]
}
```

Here is the result

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution from the following link.

https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#mentioning-users

1. get the user's id
2. wrap it with a left and right arrow with an "@" symbol beside it. syntax `<@userId>`

**usage:**

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Hey <@802AWTP13BZ>, thanks for submitting your report!"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**EDITED:** Here's how to get a userID if you don't know:

1. Search for the person.
2. Click their profile picture.
3. Then, click 'Copy member ID' like in the picture.

[image]

Comment: It does not work for me. I have tried several times but fails. Has anyone checked in on current date?

Comment: Can you add code snippet for the block section to understand the issue better

Comment: I initially thought it wasn't working for me, but as it turns out, **it does work**. I had assumed that the direct message URL contained the user's ID, but you need to retrieve it by visiting their profile, clicking on the three dots, and selecting the 'Copy member ID' option.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not work for me: the name of the user IS shown in the notification but it's not shown in the message itself.

To solve the mystery, I sent a message using the slack web client and checked the response.

Message:

```
Some text.
@O...
test
```

Response:

```
"message": {
    "user": "...",
    "type": "message",
    "ts": "...",
    "client_msg_id": "...",
    "text": "Some text. <@U0...> test",
    "team": "...",
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "rich_text",
            "block_id": "f0DGh",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "rich_text_section",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": "Some text. "
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "user",
                            "user_id": "U0..."
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "text",
                            "text": " test"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So, it turns out we need to split the message around usernames and replace usernames with an element type of `user` with the id of the corresponding user.